# Activate SRTP AES encryption at linphone console

Tags: voip, linphone, linphone-sdk

is there anybody know how to activate AES SRTP in linphone console ? I'm still not understand how to enable it. I know it related with mediastreamer2, but still can't understand it ?

Please anybody can help ?

Answer (score 1):

I've already find the answer for the question. To activate srtp in the linphone console, it is done via a configuration file usually named `linphonerc`. In the file add :

```
[sip]
media_encryption = srtp 
srtp_crypto_suites = AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_32
```

media_encryption is used to activate the srtp feature while srtp_crypto_suites is used to determine the type of AES encryption to be used.